# What does the "Unable to fork" error mean?

Tags: php, ubuntu

I'm using git for deployment, by using a POST hook on Bitbucket that executes a PHP file, this file contains the following:

```
<?php
exec('cd /var/ && git reset --hard HEAD');
exec('cd /var/ && git pull origin master');
```

This used to work fine, but lately I noticed the deployment doesn't occur when I push to Bitbucket, and when I pointed my browser to deploy.php I get the following errors:

```
Warning: exec(): Unable to fork [cd /var/ && git reset --hard HEAD] in /var/www/deploy.php on line 1 array(0) { } 
Warning: exec(): Unable to fork [cd /var/ && git pull origin master] in /var/www/deploy.php on line 2 array(0) { }
```

Not sure what went wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

I'm running on DigitalOcean Ubuntu.

Comment: Forking is something you do when you want to pull a certain version of an existing repository into a new one, thus starting your own new repository from that point. Forking isn't the end of the previous repository (original) tho. You can always merge the 2 repositories back again, but will likely be very hard after much new code is written. Forks can be very small but also very big. Think of kHTML > WebKit > Blink (Chromium's new forked engine from WebKit).

Comment: looks like the maximum number of running processes has been reached, or there is no more memory left

Comment: @hek2mgl Thanks very much, would you please make it an answer so that I can accept?

Comment: Answer of user1467267 is not wrong. But also does not help or explain what is happening here: FORKING here means starting (or forking) a PROCESS on a computer. Nothing to do with repository. PHP can not fork a process, you have to find out WHY this does not work. One hint is: '/bin/sh' is needed from PHP for executing things. Access rights, Memory-Limits or or or - maybe are another ideas..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forking in this case, means the operation to create a new process using the `fork()` system call. `fork()` usually fails because necessary system resources are exhausted, it is likely that memory limits or the maximum number of open processes per system is reached.